# How to Reduce the font size of Morris Donut graph?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, morris.js

Here is my js fiddle link [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adarshkr/pxso4zcy/1/)

I have tried out using css..but its not happening

```
svg text{
    font-size:10px!important /*but its not reducing the font size */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the style

```
svg text{
      font-size:10px!important;
}
```

In the end of your HTML (after the js includes). This will solve your problem.

***P.S:This is not the best way to solve this as morris.js by default resizes your text to fit the graph.***